# Populate a hidden form field using the div of a drop menu (drop down menu is created using divs not select, option etc)

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form.

Please note I must use divs for creating the form drop down and not the select option method etc. It just has to be done that way. The code is below.

```
<form action="url.asp" method="get">
<div class="search-button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><input type="submit" /></div>
    <div class="search-drop-down">
        <div class="title"><span>Choose Category</span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></div>
            <div class="list">
                    <div class="overflow">
                           <div class="category-entry" id="Category1">Category One</div>
                           <div class="category-entry" id="Category2">Category Two</div>
                    </div>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="search-field"><input type="text" name="search-for" id="search-for" value="" placeholder="Search for a product" /></div>
       <input type="hidden" id="ChosenCategory" name="ChosenCategory" value="CATEGORY1 OR CATEGORY2 (WHICHEVER SELECTED)" />
                                </form>
```

As shown in the code above I need to populate the hidden field value as per the chosen option which the user selects in the drop down.

I have used about 20 different variations of `getElementById` or `onFocus` functions but cannot get it to work.

The only thing I can get to work is the following JavaScript and it just populates the hidden field value with the first id ignoring completely which one has actually been selected(clicked) by the user;

```
var div = document.getElementById('DivID');
var hidden = document.getElementById('ChosenCategory');
hidden.value = div.innerHTML;
```

I'm running classic asp so if there is a vbscript way then great, otherwise if I have to use JavaScript to do it then as long as it does the job I'll be happy still.

Comment: Where are those three lines of JavaScript in your code? Is there some sort of click handler for the category options?

Comment: placed after the form element, its the click handler i assume im struggling with as everything ive tried has failed

Comment: since you are using divs instead of a select dropdown, what does your javascript look like for the click event (where the user is selecting their option)

Comment: Hi devlin, I currently have no click event as i tried so many things I am asking for options here, the suggestion from SunKnight0 didnt work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A click handler on the options could be used to update the value.

No jQuery or any other external library is needed. Below is a working example. Of course, in your case the `input` element could be of type `hidden`, but I made it `text` here for the sake of demonstration.

```js
//Add the click handlers
var options = document.getElementsByClassName('option');
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  options[i].addEventListener('click', selectOption);
}

function selectOption(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
  document.getElementById('output').value = e.target.id;
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}

div.option {
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div class="option" id="Category1">Category One</div>
   <div class="option" id="Category2">Category Two</div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="output" />
```

Comment: This worked! How do I mark this as answered! Thank you!!

Comment: @brabstah Glad I could help. There is a check mark under the voting arrows to the left of the post to mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: Thank you, think this was the only variation I didn't try, wish I had asked hours ago

Answer (score 1):

**You should be able to achieve what you're after with a fairly simple setup involving listening for clicks on two separate `<div>` elements, and then updating an `<input>` based on those clicks.**

**TL;DR:**

I've put together a jsfiddle here of what it sounds like you're trying to make work: https://jsfiddle.net/e479pcew/5/

**Long version:**

Imagine we have 2 basic elements:

- A dropdown, containing two options
- An input

Here's what it might look like in HTML:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <div id="option-one">Option 1</div>
    <div id="option-two">Option 2</div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="hidden-input">
```

The JavaScript needed to wire these elements up should be fairly easy, but let me know if it doesn't make sense! I've renamed things throughout to make things as explicit as possible, but hopefully that doesn't throw you off.

One quick thing - this is an incredibly 'naive' implementation of this idea which has a lot of potential for refactoring! However I just wanted to show in the most basic terms how to use JavaScript to make this stuff happen.

So here we go - first things first, let's find all those elements we need. We need to assign variables for the two different dropdown options, and the hidden input:

```js
var optionOne = document.getElementById("option-one");
var optionTwo = document.getElementById("option-two");
var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("hidden-input");
```

Cool. Next we need to make a function that will come in handy later. This function expects a click event as an argument. From that click event, it looks at the `id` of the element that was clicked, and assigns that id as a value to our `hiddenInput`:

```js
function valueToInput(event) {
  hiddenInput.value = event.target.id;
}
```

Great - last thing, let's start listening for the clicks on specific elements, and if we hear any, we'll fire the above `valueToInput` function:

```js
optionOne.addEventListener("click", valueToInput, false);
optionTwo.addEventListener("click", valueToInput, false);
```

That should get you going! Have a look at the jsfiddle I already linked to and see if it makes sense - get in touch if not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use JQuery in this project? It would make your life a lot easier. You can detect when a div is clicked and populate the hidden field.

This could do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.category-entry').click(function() {
        $('#ChosenCategory').val($(this).text()); }); });
```

Comment: you don't *need* jquery to detect when a div is clicked.

Comment: I have tried this but when the form is submitted ChosenCategory is empty. Anything obvious I am doing wrong

Comment: I would have to see the entire code to be able to spot problems.

devlin carnate, of course jquery is just a wrapper, you can do everything it does without it. It just makes things easier and cleaner.